# How to make the chapter title is center of page just in \mainmatter?

Tags: chapters

How to make the chapter title just in `\mainmatter` is center of page? In `\frontmatter` the chapter title is top of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}{\huge\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{20pt}{}%[\break]%[\vfill]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{6ex plus 1fill}{10ex plus 1fill}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{ABC}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{DEF}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{GOOD}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want; The chapter title vertically centered, or horizontally centered, or both?

Comment: I want : in the \frontmatter part, the chapter name directly followed by the contain of chapter, so I want the chapter name is the top of page and horizontally centered. In the \mainmatter part, I want the title of chapter in one page, and the contain of chapter is next page. I want in \mainmatter part, the chapter name is both vertically and horizontally centered (at center of paper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `\titleformat` after `\mainmatter`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}{\huge\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{20pt}{}%[\break]%[\vfill]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{6ex plus 1fill}{10ex plus 1fill}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{ABC}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{DEF}
    \mainmatter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}%
            {\vfil\huge\textsc{\chaptername} \thechapter}{20pt}%
            {}[\vfill\mbox{}\newpage]
    \chapter{GOOD}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```